# excel: закрашивание текста в зависимости от условия без использования VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-формулы, оформление

Подскажите, возможно ли вообще в таблице excel изменение параметров ячейки (цвет текста, цвет фона) в зависимости от того, что содержится в ячейке без создания VBA макроса и запуска его по мере надобности

Т.е. позволяет ли Excel для ячейки прописать такие программируемые свойства или только макрос?

Например, в столбце А указаны даты и я хочу подсветить все понедельники

Comment: Откройте для себя ["Условное форматирование"](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: + использовать функцию *деньнед ()*